# C# + UWP + Console Application + MSVS2017 = not (always) working

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, console-application

My internet searches have led me to downloading the project templates for UWP Console applications in C#, which work perfectly in VS2019, but unfortunately our build machine uses VS2017 and I am forced to "downgrade" (i.e. setup the project again) for that version.

The application is not extremely complicated. It connects to a BLE device, registers to a specific characteristic, prints the received data and also sends it through TCP/IP to a server for visualization. All in all less than 700 lines of code. For the usage of Bluetooth and TCP/IP I have found a couple of checkboxes in the manifest, which I enabled.

Compiling in VS2017 seemed like a roll of the dice, but I think I have found the pattern now. Release mode (whether it is for x86 or x64) will never work. It gives me 168 errors of which over 100 are "Loading assembly "XXX.dll" failed. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.". 100 different XXX.dlls, always related to System.Private.CoreLib.

In debug mode, it is a different story. The first attempt fails, with only one XXX.dll (System.Runtime.dll, and still related to System.Private.CoreLib), but when I do a 'Clean Solution' and compile again, compiling and linking succeeds. Do I clean and compile again, the error pops up again. Clean and compile again? -> Error gone. It seems to ping-pong ad infinitum between success and failure.

Any other relevant information may be that the minimum and target Windows versions are 2004 (10.0, build 19041).

I am afraid the situation I am in is very specific and therefore I can't find a solution, but maybe someone here is able to help.

Comment: What's the version of the VS 2017? Just checked the [Console App (Universal) Project Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewWhitechapelMSFT.ConsoleAppUniversal), it requires VS 2017 Version 15.7 or later.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Locally I have 15.1, but there is hope: the build machine has 15.9.42. Hopefully the local VS2017 can be updated. Stay tuned for more. :)

Comment: It appears that was indeed the problem. Frustrating that it is something that simple that I overlooked. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Roy Li for pointing out that the project templates have a minimum version of VS 2017. I upgraded it and now everything compiles.